# Extjs grid filter empty and not emptey checkbox

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I want overwrite grid filter to filter empty and not empty checkbox

Comment: What grid filter you meen?

Answer (score 0):

If store is already exists, you can add filter

```
store.addFilter(function(rec){
    return rec.get('dataIndex name') === true; // or other flag. if it's bool value === no need;
});
```

in new store you can add filter

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/users',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users'
         }
     },
     filters: [
        function(rec) {
            return rec.get('dataIndex name') === true;
        }
    ]
 });
```